# Stripe Api is having issue while creating a payment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stripe-payments

> when i try to execute this my data is successfully be stored in
> database but unfortunately when it comes with stripe api it gives an error
> which i've mentioned below seems like its an error of parameter missing I don't know. Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong

//method for creating payment

```
exports.createpayment=async (req,res)=>{
    const payment= await paymentdata.create(req.body) 
   
   stripe.customers.create({
       
    source: req.body.stripeToken,
    fullname: req.body.fullname,
    address: req.body.fullname
})
.then((customer) => {

    return stripe.charges.create({
        amount: req.body.amount,     // Charing Rs 25
        
        currency: 'INR',
        customer: fullname
    });
})
.then((charge) => {
    res.send("Success")  // If no error occurs
})
.catch((err) => {
    res.send(err)       // If some error occurs
});
}
```

//error while running stripe Api

```
    "type": "StripeInvalidRequestError",
    "raw": {
        "code": "parameter_unknown",
        "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
        "message": "Received unknown parameter: fullname",
        "param": "fullname",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "headers": {
            "server": "nginx",
            "date": "Mon, 27 Dec 2021 11:04:48 GMT",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "content-length": "242",
            "connection": "keep-alive",
            "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
            "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE",
            "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
            "access-control-expose-headers": "Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required",
            "access-control-max-age": "300",
            "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store",
            "idempotency-key": "30b9c551-4596-4b35-ad09-abc6dfbb3d58",
            "original-request": "req_dcy6NACGsy6EJP",
            "request-id": "req_dcy6NACGsy6EJP",
            "stripe-version": "2020-08-27",
            "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload"
        },
        "statusCode": 400,
        "requestId": "req_dcy6NACGsy6EJP"
    },
    "rawType": "invalid_request_error",
    "code": "parameter_unknown",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
    "param": "fullname",
    "headers": {
        "server": "nginx",
        "date": "Mon, 27 Dec 2021 11:04:48 GMT",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "content-length": "242",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
        "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE",
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "access-control-expose-headers": "Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required",
        "access-control-max-age": "300",
        "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store",
        "idempotency-key": "30b9c551-4596-4b35-ad09-abc6dfbb3d58",
        "original-request": "req_dcy6NACGsy6EJP",
        "request-id": "req_dcy6NACGsy6EJP",
        "stripe-version": "2020-08-27",
        "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload"
    },
    "requestId": "req_dcy6NACGsy6EJP",
    "statusCode": 400
}
```

//here is my model schema

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const paymentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

fullname:[{
    type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId ,
    ref: "userdata",
    required:true
    

}], 
    
cvc:{
    type:String
},

country:{
    type:String,
    
    
},
address:{
    type:String,
    
    
},

cardnumber:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    
},
expires:{
    type:String
},
amount:{
    type:String
}

})

module.exports=mongoose.model('paymentdata', paymentSchema);
```

Comment: stripe is expecting the key to be `name` instead of `fullname`  in the customer object. For more info see here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create

Comment: @aravind_reddy you should add this as an answer to get credit.

Comment: The clue is in the raw.message attribute: "Received unknown parameter: fullname"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating payment instead of `fullname`  use  `name`

```
stripe.customers.create({
    source: req.body.stripeToken,
    name: req.body.fullname,
    address: req.body.fullname
})
```

Answer (score 0):

stripe is expecting the key to be `name` instead of `fullname` in the customer object. For more info see here: [stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create](http://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create)